# Adding additional methods to all Form Controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Well basically I'm using this:

```
<form ng-model="form" ng-submit="save()" name="form" class="form">
```

And it creates a new form controller, right? I'd like to add a method "addErrors" for all my form controllers in my application, now I have to do it manually, is there a way to add it through config or run method when I'm bootstraping my app?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little known fact:
There can be multiple directives with the same name. Each one does **not** overwrite the previous, but rather gets applied along-side all the others.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to define a custom directive for `form` elements (you will in fact need two: one for `form` and one for `ngForm`) that gets access to the `FormController` instance and augments it with custom behaviour.

E.g.:

```
app.directive('form', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'form',   // to get access to the FormController instance
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {
            formCtrl.submit = function () {
                alert(formCtrl.$valid ? '*Submit*' : '*Error*');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2nnFJ/)**.

Comment: it seems to work perfect! And I still get the properties of the original FormController.

Thank you!

Comment: Always glad to help ! Feel free to also upvote the answer if you really liked it :)

Comment: The same does not seem to be working for ngForm - any idea why?

Comment: I created a plunk to demonstrate... http://plnkr.co/edit/yxVGuZr7WvKgXFcTETpP?p=preview

Comment: For some reason, I'm able to create other methods, but not "submit".

Comment: `ngSubmit` hooks to the `submit` event. `ngForm` does not emit `submit` events. Only real `<form>` elements do.